# Python: Sort a list alphabetically, but with all lowercase letters given priority over capital letters

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of single digits (0-9) and single letters (aA-zZ), these are represented as strings. I'd like to sort 
this list so that when sorted this list looks like below:

```
['0',..'1',..'2',..'a',..'b',..'c',....'z', 'A',.. 'B',.. 'C'.., 'Z']
```

so far every method of sorting that I've seen has paired the letters together such that 'A' follows 'a' and so on. Is there a way to sort this list such that capital letters are given the lowest priority?

Comment: What is actually in the list? Are they all strings?

Comment: Yes the list is actually all strings, I'll edit my post to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `key` argument of `sort` or `sorted` to define whatever kind of ordering you like. Example:

```
>>> s = "123ABCabc"
>>> print sorted(s, key=lambda c: c.lower() if c.isupper() else c.upper())
['1', '2', '3', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'A', 'B', 'C']
```

Here, if a letter is lower case, we treat it as upper case for the purposes of sorting, and vice versa. characters with no case, such as digits, are unchanged.

Comment: `print(sorted(s,key=lambda x: x.isupper()`?

Comment: Ooh, that's a nicely concise approach. It also demonstrates that the return value of the lambda isn't restricted to strings. It can be a boolean or an integer, etc